# Count rows by year and add row with 0 value if no result

Tags: mysql

Assuming that I have a MySQL table with those rows :

```
Name | date
-----------
A | 2016
B | 2016
C | 2016
B | 2015
B | 2015
C | 2014
A | 2014
```

How can I count rows by name to have a result like this one (assuming that I want to count years between 2013 and 2016):

```
Name | date | COUNT(Name)
-------------------------
A | 2016    | 1
B | 2016    | 1
C | 2016    | 1
A | 2015    | 0
B | 2015    | 2
C | 2015    | 0
A | 2014    | 1
B | 2014    | 0
C | 2014    | 1
A | 2013    | 0
B | 2013    | 0
C | 2013    | 0
```

As yu can see, I need to "add" rows in result set for the year if they appeare at least one time in an other year (there must be "more" results than existing rows) ! And for example, as I want to count years starting from 2013, if there are no rows in table in need result too.

Thank you,
Vince

Comment: Consider handling the logic of missing results in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cross join` to generate the rows.  Then use `left join` and aggregate for the counts.

```
select t.name, y.yyyy, count(t.name)
from (select distinct name from t) n cross join
     (select 2013 as yyyy union all select 2014 union all select 2015 union all select 2016) y left join
     t 
     on t.date = y.yyyy and t.name = n.name
group by t.name, y.yyyy;
```

Comment: It will be tricky if we want to use the range query for years. Maybe worth trying with a `@variable`?

Comment: Tank you  ! You just forgot to add the "LEFT JOIN"  key words between before "on t.date...".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT *,count(*) as c FROM mytable group by date, name
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Name, Date, Count(Name) FROM table 
Group By Name, Date